# How would i make this tic tac toe game have a replay option

Tags: java

I have to make a tic tac toe game for my class and need to implement a replay feature at the end. I have had various attempts from other posts from the site that were listed but cant get any to work. Any input on how to have the game reset on when y is entered after the game ends is very appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe 
{

 char[][] table = new char[3][3]; //make board

    public void gameStart() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) 
            {
                table[i][p] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean checkLegal(int row, int column) // as name
    {
        if ((row > 2 || column > 2) || (row < 0 || column < 0)) 

        {
            return true;
        }

        else if (table[row][column] == 'x' || table[row][column] == 'o') 

        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void changeBoard(char player, int row, int column) 
    {
        table[row][column] = player;

    }

    public void showBoard()  // displays board 
    {
        System.out.println("  0  " + table[0][0] + "|" + table[0][1] + "|" + table[0][2]);
        System.out.println("    --+-+--");
        System.out.println("  1  " + table[1][0] + "|" + table[1][1] + "|" + table[1][2]);
        System.out.println("    --+-+--");
        System.out.println("  2  " + table[2][0] + "|" + table[2][1] + "|" + table[2][2]);
        System.out.println("     0 1 2 ");
    }


    public char changePlayer(char player) 
    {
        char newTurn = 'e';
        if (player == 'o') {
            newTurn = 'x';
        }
        if (player == 'x') {
            newTurn = 'o';
        }
        return newTurn;
    }


    public boolean winChecker() 
    {
        if (table[0][0] == table[1][0] && table[1][0] == table[2][0] && (table[0][0] == 'x' || table[0][0] == 'o')) 

        {
            return true;
        } 

        else if (table[0][1] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[2][1] && (table[0][1] == 'x' || table[0][1] == 'o'))

        {
            return true;
        } 

        else if (table[0][2] == table[1][2] && table[1][2] == table[2][2] && (table[0][2] == 'x' || table[0][2] == 'o')) 

        {
            return true;
        } 

        else if (table[0][0] == table[0][1] && table[0][1] == table[0][2] && (table[0][0] == 'x' || table[0][0] == 'o')) 

        {
            return true;
        } 

        else if (table[1][0] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[1][2] && (table[1][0] == 'x' || table[1][0] == 'o')) 

        {
            return true;
        } 

        else if (table[2][0] == table[2][1] && table[2][1] == table[2][2] && (table[2][0] == 'x' || table[2][0] == 'o')) 

        {
            return true;
        } 

        else if (table[0][0] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[2][2] && (table[0][0] == 'x' || table[0][0] == 'o')) 

        {
            return true;
        } 

        else if (table[2][0] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[0][2] && (table[2][0] == 'x' || table[2][0] == 'o')) 

        {
            return true;
        } 

        else

        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean tieCheck() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) 
            {
                if (table[i][p] == ' ') 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


public void replayChoose()
{
          Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\n Would you like to play again? y/n");

    char replay = r.next().charAt(0);

    if(replay != 'y')
{
    System.exit(0);
}
else
{
    table = new char[3][3];
    gameStart();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {

        char player = 'o';
        int row, column;
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        TicTacToe g = new TicTacToe();

        g.gameStart();
        System.out.println("Game ready !\n");
                g.showBoard();

        while (true)
        {
            player = g.changePlayer(player);
            System.out.print("\n" + player + " ,choose your location enter each seperatly (row, column):");
            row = k.nextInt();
            column = k.nextInt();

            while (g.checkLegal(row, column)) 

            {
                System.out.println("That spot is already taken or does not exist, try again (row, column).");
                g.showBoard();
                row = k.nextInt();
                column = k.nextInt();
            }

            g.changeBoard(player, row, column);
            g.showBoard();

            if (g.winChecker())

            {
                System.out.println("\nThe winner is " + player + " !");
                g.replayChoose();
                break;

            }

            if (g.tieCheck()) 

            {
                System.out.println("\nThe game is a tie !");
                g.replayChoose();

                break;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the gameplay (after variable declarations, etc.) portion of your main() inside of a while loop? Something like this:

```
while (keyEntered != 'y') {
    //gameplay code...
    keyEntered = getPlayAgain();  //ask for user input
}
```

Before the game restarts you would have to empty all the appropriate variables. (like the table)

Comment: so wait after variables declared I put main into the while loop but at what part of main would it be out of the loop? or does the whole main go in the loop?

Comment: Declare and initialize the variables separately. Declare all the variables that are used in the main right below the "public static void main(String[] args) {" and then initialize them inside of the loop. Whenever the loop iterates it should reset all the variables to the original values and then begin the game. @JosephBorowski

Answer (score 0):

Extract all the come in the main() method to a new method called game(). Then call the method game from the main().

After finishing, initialize the table array and then call the method game():

```
if (replay != 'y') {
    System.exit(0);
} else {
    table = new char[3][3];
    game();
}
```